# Book: Learning ROS for Robotics Programming, 2nd Edn; Chapter 5 - USB Camera is not running

Tags: ros, usb-cam, usb-camera, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and jade version of ROS. I am trying to use the usb camera by the method given in the book on page 187. My camera is already good and I checked it by the "cheese" method explained in there. Here is what I am doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-usb-cam

$ roslaunch chapter5_tutorials usb_cam.launch view:=true
```

here is what I am getting after doing this

```
[ERROR] [1453172400.684518103]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...


[ERROR] [1453172400.684518103]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...
```

Can any please tell me, how can I solve this problem? After getting Stefan Kohlbrecher; I am going to add the steps I took. Thank you so much Stefan Kohlbrecher for your kind response. Here is what I followed from your prescribed solution from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/212847/how-to-get-usb-camera-frame/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/131331/usb_cam-errorwebcam-expected-picture-but-didnt-get-it/) and also from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/131331/usb_cam-errorwebcam-expected-picture-but-didnt-get-it/).

```
rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv
roslaunch chapter5_tutorials usb_cam.launch view:=true
```

and here is what I got,

```
[ERROR] [1453352737.003836186]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...
[mjpeg @ 0x1ffd7c0] mjpeg: unsupported coding type (cd)
[ERROR] [1453352737.043623383]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it...
```

I don't know why the code, commands and method shown in book is still not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224431/book:-learning-ros-for-robotics-programming,-2nd-edn;-chapter-5---usb-camera-is-not-running/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-02**:
See update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [google search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22expected%20picture%20but%20didn%27t%20get%20it%22&rct=j) mostly ending up here on ROS Answers suggests that this has to do with the wrong pixel format being set. See [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/131331/usb_cam-errorwebcam-expected-picture-but-didnt-get-it/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/212847/how-to-get-usb-camera-frame/).

Note that you need to make sure that you set the described param in the correct namespace of the camera driver. The pixel format likely depends on the camera, so you might have to play around with multiple formats. Alternatively, you could check which ones are available using other tools such as guvcview.

/edit: As described above you probably want to find out first what formats your camera supports. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/639738/how-can-i-list-the-available-video-modes-for-a-usb-webcam-in-linux) are some methods for doing so. For instance,

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats
```

as described there should do the trick. You can edit your question with that additional information.

/edit2: As I mentioned above **you need to make sure that you set the described param in the correct namespace of the camera driver**. It looks like you are using [this launch file](https://github.com/AaronMR/Learning_ROS_for_Robotics_Programming_2nd_edition/blob/hydro-devel/chapter5_tutorials/launch/usb_cam.launch). The camera uses the `camera` name there, hence you need to set the parameter accordingly:

```
rosparam set camera/pixel_format yuyv
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-05-18**:
That worked for me. Thank you!